# On javascript software breaking down structure guidelines

Tags: javascript, closures, prototype, scoping, modular

I'm trying to refactor my old Colorchess (ChessHighlight) program. It's a chess board aimed to enhance influences of chessmen on each turn to help beginners understanding the game.

According to pressure balance on board at a given turn, tiles are colorized as follows :

- green = no pressure
- white = white player owns the tile
- black = black player owns the tile
- a color picked from a gradient green-yellow-orange-red : conflictual situation for this tile

AI's in project but for the moment I focus on making this game playable correctly along devices, in both situations : table gaming on tablet -or- network gaming.

I decide to code the client side in javascript, I love it ! and servers syncing will be in PHP, since my actual hosting environment is under.

My questions and though comes when I try to put all together :

(client-side libraries)
  - RequireJS --> loading files
  - KnockoutJS --> binding UI events
  - ICanHaz --> templating
  - Zepto --> DOM manipulating
  - and maybe underscoreJS for utilities

I'm worry about making spaghetti code, difficult to understand and maintain.

In the old program, ChessHighlight, there was lots of interlaced construct declarations and prototype extensions, for example :

```
// file board.js
function Board() { ... }
function Tile() { ... }

// next included file :
function Chessman() { ... }

// again in a third included file
// since board and chessmen are defined 
Tile.prototype.put(chessman) { ... }
Tile.prototype.empty() { ... }
```

due to nature highly-coupled of the game, each file inclusion in the stack carry more and more definitions, and code became messy...

A difficulty is that the game need transactional implementation since I did setters like :

```
// both... (think ACID commit in a RDBMS)
tile_h8.chessman = rook_white_1;
rook_white_1.tile = tile_h8;
```

Now I solve -partially- this issue by creating a "Object Relational Pool Manager" which is intended to store :

- references to objects of any kind (Board, Chessman, Tile, Influence...)
- the relations between objects
- and appreciably some type checks and cardinality/arity summing

(I'm baking the code at this time)

SOME  QUESTIONS :

- How to write extensible code (elegantly, no classes and interface simulation, rather prototypes and closures) in a way that you define basic atoms of code : Tile, Board, Chessman in very short files, and then gluing them together in an other part : adding behavior wirh callbacks ?

NOTE : I try to read game engines code (Crafty, Quintus...) but Core of these engines (1600 lines of code), although they are well documented, are difficult to understand (where is the starting point ? where are runtime flows ??)

- UML : I have the feeling that classical methodologies could rapidly fail with closures, callbacks and nested scopes, I seems to be instinctive to write and understand, but drawing dragrams seems to be a trick... what good JS developers use as a safety rope to climb 1500+ line-of-code peaks ?

  - and the last : I would have an engine API "jquery-like" to plug it easily into computed observables the KnockOut ViewModels of the GUI. Something like this

[code]

```
var colorchess = new Colorchess( my_VM_for_this_DIV_part );
colorchess.reset( "standard-game" );
colorchess("a1") --> a wrapper for "a1" tile
colorchess("h8").chessman() --> a wrapper for "h8" tile's chessman (rook)

// iterate on black chessman
colorchess("black").each( function( ref, chessman) {})

// a chainable example
colorchess("white").chessman("queen").influences()
```

[/code]

... but for for moment, I don't know exactly how to model, write and test those kind of mutable objects.

Suggestions are welcome. Thanks for help.

Comment: I hope your code is more cohesive than your questions.

Comment: I know. It's not easy to explaim a so complicated problem. I ll restyle a bit my question to make it clearer...

Comment: @HMR : by ACID, I was meaning : given two objects A and B, perform simultaneously  A.b = B and B.a = A... making the cross-reference atomically (to avoid a third object to pollute these two assignements)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that defining your objects in constructor functions is bad. Defining them as closures is worse because it'll consume more resources and isn't as easily optimized by JS engines.

Tightly coupled objects is a problem you'll have with closures as well, you can use mediator pattern for that. Mediator can complicate your code but you can easily control the application flow after you set it up.

Having good tools for your JS project is important in big projects, I've tried some; like Google closure compiler with Eclipse, Visual Studio with typescript and now trying Dart (google Dart) with Dart editor (=Eclipse with right plugins). This can help you spot inconsistencies quickly and refactor easier. Typescript would be the only one where it would be easy to use JS libraries because Typescript is JS with optional extensions. Not sure how AngularJS is coming along with the Dart port but that is something worth looking at.

As for ACID, if you're talking about updating the sate of your client side object in a way that it reflect the data in the server's database. You can use promise instead of callbacks. That will improve readability of XHR updates. Write your PHP so you'll have update messages with the desired state of both the piece and the tile so it can change the data in a transaction.